# SQL - joining multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have three tables that I'm trying to join:

- sales
- order
- employee

For example, the tables have the following attributes.

**Sales:**

- ID
- price

**Order:**

- ID
- tag

**Employee:**

- tag
- yearsWorked

I would like to keep only records that exist from the result of a left join in sales and order -> left join the result with employee

```
SELECT *

FROM ( SELECT *

FROM SALES

LEFT JOIN ORDER

ON SALES.ID = ORDER.ID) AS SO 

LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE

on SO.TAG = EMPLOEYE.TAG;
```

The above query does not work.

Comment: This is entirely unrelated to CrossValidated and should be migrated to StackOverflow, if left open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a subquery. All you have to do is 2 LEFT JOIN, each for the respective table. This will make sure that only the results of the first left join are joined with the third table.

```
SELECT *
FROM SALES S
LEFT JOIN ORDER O ON S.ID = O.ID 
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON O.TAG = E.TAG;
```

I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
*
FROM
    Order
    LEFT JOIN Sales 
        ON Order.ID = Sales.ID
    LEFT JOIN Employee 
        ON Order.tag = Employee.tag
```